# optimal way to highlight selected li in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-class

I am using Angularjs 1.4.7 version. I have a `<ul><li>..</li>....</ul>` and want to apply a `background-color` property to the selected `li`. The code is as below:

```
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="menu-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-model="selectedElement" ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedElement}">
          <a href="">{{item.key}} - {{item.value}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Inside the controller I have mapped the `$scope.selectedElement = 0` so by default the first `li` element gets the `.selected` class property.

But when I click on the `li` element I need to apply the `.selected` class. I can bind a `ng-click` function passing the `$index` and set the `selectedElement` to the index, but can we do it just with the `ng-class` directive. Please let me know if this possible and where I am going wrong in my current approach.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-model` won't work on li and `$index` is not reliable .

Try like this

Create a method on scope

```
$scope.markSelected=function(item){
  item.isSelected = true;
  $scope.items.filter(function(x){ return x.key != item.key; }).map(function(x){  
   x.isSelected=false;
  })
}
```

then put it on view

```
<li class="menu-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="markSelected(item)" ng-class="{selected: item.isSelected }">
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/c1d0dtcs/3/)**</kbd>